# Javascript - Detect Youtube Default-Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, image, youtube-api

Is there any way to see if a Youtube Thumbnail really exists or Youtube just replaced it by the default thumbnail?

For example, a video without this thumbnail : http://img.youtube.com/vi/G75WApUdYJ4/maxresdefault.jpg
And one with an existing thumbnail : http://img.youtube.com/vi/pkyLAWX5V30/maxresdefault.jpg

Story:
I just tried to use Youtube's maxresdefault-Thumbnails as background for my "Media-Player-Page".
Using normal images works fine but for any reasom some Youtube Videos don't have a maxresdefault-Thumbnail. If i load this image I just get the small default Thumbnail which isn't really enjoyable on a FullHD Screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than serving up the default image, you could use [0.jpg](http://img.youtube.com/vi/G75WApUdYJ4/0.jpg), [1.jpg](http://img.youtube.com/vi/G75WApUdYJ4/1.jpg), [2.jpg](http://img.youtube.com/vi/G75WApUdYJ4/2.jpg), or [3.jpg](http://img.youtube.com/vi/G75WApUdYJ4/3.jpg) (see [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)).

If that doesn't work for your needs, you could compare the Base64 encoding of each image, as defined in this answer: [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks! It was not the solution I was looking for but it gave me a little kick. I just added a second (hidden) imagetag which automatically resizes itself on the embeded image's size and read it's width with Javascript. If the .offsetWidth equals 120 it's a default Youtube-Thumbnail and can be repaced.

Comment: Glad to help, and smart thinking!