# Detecting "Missing Video" Youtube Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, youtube, youtube-api

Greetings from a future caveman,

I load a lot of youtube thumbnails on my page. They load from thumbnail urls I have in my db.

From time to time the video in question is changed or deleted by the author on youtube. This leaves me with 2 problems:

1. I'm loading the blank picture from youtube

[image]

2. In my db I still have this image url listed.

What would be a solution for figuring out the "missing video" thumnail, NOT displaying it, and updating my db. I need to fire an event by recognizing this image. Note that this is the default "missing" image that can appear different urls. So it's not a simple matter of seeing a particular url.

I also thought of using youtube api but making a bunch of calls every time the page loads seems counterintuitive to me.

I need to detect the image and fire so some of even for JS/jquery to use to update my db via ajax.

Maybe I'm overthinking this so if anybody has another solution to my problem I'm open.

### **I have read this: [Javascript - Detect Youtube Default-Thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917664/javascript-detect-youtube-default-thumbnail)**

But the solution above does not seem to fit. The first option in the answer is what I'm doing now and it doesn't work - because youtube serves the default image even when you use 1.jpg, or 2 etc..  (which is what I use). Basically the video is gone.

The second option (base 64 encoding, creating canvas element etcc) is not really expanded upon and seems rather like using a chainsaw in place of a scalpel.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I'm using

`http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video_id>/mqdefault.jpg`
,

it will display the trimmed (no black borders at top and bottom) YouTube thumbnail. The dimensions of this are `320 x 180`px.

Whereas if there is no available thumbnail, you will get YouTube's fallback thumbnail, but that is actually `120 x 90`px.

So here's a much easier way for figuring out if you got an invalid thumbnail (as compared to reading base64 data from the `<img>` tag).

Hope this helps.