# How to detect a missing YouTube video thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api

I have a custom YouTube player which displays an image that the video owner can set to one that they specify or to one of the YouTube thumbnail images that get created when the video is uploaded. This thumbnail image is displayed before the video starts and after it finishes playing in my player.

If the video owner, who had registered their video in my web-app, doesn't pick an image, I still want to show one of the YouTube's thumbnails, but sometimes I get the funny three eyed cassette looking image, indicating that that image doesn't exist.

In another StackOverflow question about this subject, it was suggested that missing images have a specific width and height, [Detecting “Missing Video” Youtube Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177908/detecting-missing-video-youtube-image), but I've found that non-missing images also have the same width and height values, so that isn't really a good final determiner of whether the images exists or not.

Does anyone have another way to do this?

Perhaps color testing in the image after is it put into a hidden `img` tag; and if so how to do this?

Alternatively, I'm using the YouTube Embedded Video JavaScript API, but I haven't seen a way to access the video's associated thumbnails using it.  I've read that version 3 had some support for this, but requires some sort of login to use it, so I don't think that'll work for me.

Thank you.